# msxsl:node-set() and position() are not working together

Tags: xslt

I've got an xsl:variable that contains a pre-processed set (DoesNotContainChildElement).  I think msxsl:node-set() is adding a root element so position is always 1.  But what I need it the top 15 elements.

```
<xsl:variable name="Summary">
<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($DoesNotContainChildElement)">
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 16">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the function `msxsl:node-set` does not add any root node, it is simply that with XSLT 1.0 a sample like

```
<xsl:variable name="rtf1">
  <item>1</item>
  <item>2</item>
  <item>3</item>
</xsl:variable>
```

creates [a result tree fragment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Result-Tree-Fragments) and "A result tree fragment is treated equivalently to a node-set that contains just a single root node". So in the sample above we have a result tree fragment with a single root node containing three `item` child elements.

Applying the `msxsl:node-set(rtf1)` extension function then gives you a `node-set` instead of a result tree fragment where now the node-set contains a single root node with three `item` child elements. Thus if you want to access the `item` elements you need `msxsl:node-set($rtf1)/*` or more general `msxsl:node-set($rtf1)/node()` to access all child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `msxsl:node-set($DoesNotContainChildElement)/*`. If it's true that `msxsl:node-set()` adds a root node, then adding `/*` to your path will iterate over the children, where you can test for position.

Alternatively you could simply use `<xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($DoesNotContainChildElement)/*" mode="testposition"/>` and `<xsl:template match="*" mode="testposition">…`.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one variable $DoesNotContainChildElement so a for-each will only yield value 1 for position().
You can check that by running the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$x">
    <pos1><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></pos1>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="$x/*">
    <pos2><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></pos2>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Where x is a (node-set type) variable.
The result will look something like

```
<pos1>1</pos1>
<pos2>1</pos2>
<pos2>2</pos2>
<pos2>3</pos2>
<pos2>...</pos2>
```

Adding `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` will result in the output of the entire variable contents in case of the first for-each above, whereas for the second for-each it will result in the output of each sub-element of the variable one-by-one.
The second form is the one to use if you wish to output only selected sub-elements.
The same holds when you first apply the node-set function to change an rtf into a node-set.